# Object prototype does not "live update"

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the following piece of code:

```
var Test = function () {
};
Test.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  return "done";
};
```

Now, I create an object of Test

```
var t = new Test();
alert(t.doSomething());    // Correct alerts "done"
```

Now I add another method to the prototype:

```
Test.prototype.fly = function() { return "fly"; };
alert(t.fly());       // Correctly alerts "fly" (existing objects get "live udpated")
```

Now, I make the prototype point to a blank object:

```
Test.prototype = {};
alert(t.doSomething());    // Continues to alert "done", but why?
alert(t.fly());            // Continues to alert "fly", but why?

var t2 = new Test();
alert(t.doSomething());    // As expected, this does not work
```

1. When I add a method to prototype, it reflects correctly on all new and existing objects
2. When I "blank" out the prototype by doing `<name>.prototype = {};`, it only "blanks" out new instances, but not existing ones. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: @raina77ow I think this question is little different.

Comment: @thefourtheye Of course, because it's a subset of the questions answered in that thread.

Comment: Objects keep their own reference copy to their `prototype` object (via [`[[Prototype]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)). Augmenting that object from the constructor's `prototype` property will be reflected in existing instances, but replacing it won't (since that only affects 1 copy). And, once ES6 is standard, you'll be able to set the instance's copy using [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An analogy is this:

```
var a = {foo : 'bar'};
var b = a; //the same object as a
var c = a;
var d = a;

a.apple = 'orange';

a = 1;  //a === 1. b, c and d stay the same, pointing to the object with apple
```

What I did here is replace what `a` was pointing, but not the object itself.

When you added `fly`, you are modifying that single prototype object which all instances share, the object that `Test.prototype` is currently pointing to.

But when you assigned a blank object to `Test.prototype`, you modified what `Test.prototype` was pointing to. It does not modify what the existing instances are pointing to. But from this point on, any new instances will now use the new object on `Test.prototype` as their prototype object.

If you are familiar with C, I'd rather think of JS variables as pointers rather than references.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completing the previous answer, if you want reflect your changes on all instances you must update the prototype correctly.

Prototype property is an object and you can delete a propery with the reserved keyword 'delete'.

If you want delete 'doSomething' property :

```
delete Test.prototype.doSomething;
```

Answer (score 0):

consider

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype = {a:{"VMAddress":"@1234"}}
```

consider that Foo.prototype.a object has VMAddress "@1234"
if you create object now then,

```
var f1 = new Foo();
```

now f1.a will point to the same object ie with Virtual Machine address "@1234"
if you look

```
f1.a === Foo.prototype.a ;//prints tue
```

If you change prototype to some other value now,

```
Foo.prototype = {a:{"VMAddress":"@5678"}}
```

and if you create object now then,

```
var f2 = new Foo();
```

although

```
f2.a === Foo.prototype.a; //prints true because both point to same VM address @5678
```

but

```
f1.a === f2.a; //prints false
```

why??
    because their VM address are different(one is @1234 and other is @5678) and infact they are different object

final verdict 
the prototype chain at the time of object creation decides what an object's prototype will be.